# Another instance of mysql query join

Tags: mysql, join

I have the following tables -

1. a transaction table with the following fields -

   `transactionId`,
   `userId`,
   `merchantId`
2. A user table with `userID` and `details`
3. A merchant table with `merchantId` and `details`

There could be some transactions entries for which merchantId is null.

I want to get a report of transactions with `merchantId` and merchant details as well. All the transactions should be there in the report. For transactions without merchant ID, the merchant fields can be NULL.

A LEFT join like this is not returning the entries for `merchantId` null, because the `merchantId` field is null in the transaction table -

**Query :**

```
SELECT vt.*,
       u.userDetails,
       m.merchantId,
       m.merchantDetails
FROM TRANSACTION AS vt
LEFT JOIN merchant AS m ON vt.merchantId = m.merchantId
JOIN users AS u ON vt.userId = u.userID;
```

Can this be done with join alone?

Comment: Please include sample data, table definitions and expected output in your question

Comment: Are you sure it's not failing because the user does not exist?

Answer (score 0):

Your query works as it should. It returnes all transactions from table 'transaction' and if merchantId is NULL than merchant details are null ... but transaction is still on the list.

See for yourself (I inserted 4 transactions including 1 with NULL in merchantId field):

[SQLFiddle DEMO](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/dd9ca2/1)